# Combinatorics of sums

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Let's say that we have a number S that represents a sum. This sum can be broken down into a sum of terms. I want to calculate how many expressions I can write that represent that sum where terms are in the range from $ 1 $ to $ S $.

> Example:
>   $$\begin{align}    
>     4 &= 1 + 1 + 1 + 1\\
>     4 &= 2 + 1 + 1\\
>     4 &= 1 + 2 + 1\\
>     4 &= 1 + 1 + 2\\
>     4 &= 2 + 2\\
>     4 &= 3 + 1\\
>     4 &= 1 + 3\\
>     4 &= 4
> \end{align}
> $$
>   For $S=4$ we have $N=8$ .
>   For $S=3$, we have $N=4$

Although I figured out that I can calculate that with this formula:

$N = 2^{S-1}$

I can't really tell why is that. I can count them for few sums and see the rule but is there a better way to explain this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Pascal's triangle. Notice how each subsequent line is created by summing up its previous lines. For example, let's see the 4 example. See the fourth line, which says 1 3 3 1. This means there are 1 way to sum 4 with 4 integers, 3 ways to sum 4 with 3 integers, 3 ways to sum 4 with 2 integers, and 1 way to sum 4 into 1 integer. And the sum of each row of Pascal's triangle is $2^{S-1}$.

Comment: Oh, I should've thought about that! It seems to be closest to a theory I need.

Answer (score 7):

Hint: Imagine $S$ balls lined up in a row. Between each pair of adjacent balls, you can choose whether to put a "divider" between them or not. After considering all such possible pairs, you can group the balls according to the dividers. For example, $4=1+1+2$ can be depicted as `*|*|**` where `|` denotes a divider, and `*` denotes a ball.

Comment: I figured this out but wasn't really aware if there is a theory in place that explains that or I have to prove through mathematical induction that my formula stands for any number S.